# Python data frames to csv - array elements to separate columns

Tags: python, csv

Python data frames. I have a data frame which has integer array list in each row. How do I write this to a csv file where each occurance of the array gets in respective columns of the csv.

I tried to csv command

However all my row elements are getting into one column in csv file.

df is as below

```
[123, 1234, 2334]
[2345, 12, 12345, 4566, 567]
[12, 1233, 112]
```

I want to get 123,2345,12 in 1st column of csv, 1234,12,1233 in second column of csv etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'd suggest using the `pandas` library, it has a nice `read_csv` method which makes this sort of thing easy

Comment: You need to show your original dataframe, at least part of it

Comment: 0                     [8692, 802, 803, 807, 8462, 8692]
1                  [8298, 4772, 7921, 7916, 7918, 7920]
2            [8692, 8692, 8312, 1858, 8310, 8300, 8300]
3                              [8474, 7946, 8692, 7837]
4                              [9211, 9208, 9209, 9210]
5                              [8312, 4128, 8290, 8291]
6                                  [732, 808, 807, 791]
7     [7946, 8312, 7448, 2911, 7921, 7916, 8312, 744...
8     [8692, 8312, 8298, 7921, 7926, 8312, 8298, 117...

Comment: this is how df looks like . in Each row it is an integer array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of fantastic reasons to use pandas or numpy for this. So don't do the following.

Assuming that the lists are themselves in a list:

```
df = [[123,1234,2334], [2345,12,12345,4566,567], [12,1233,112]]
sep = ","
print("\n".join([sep.join(list(map(str, x))) for x in df]), file=file)
```

Results in:

```
123,1234,2334 
2345,12,12345,4566,567
12,1233,112
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this resolution . It did resolve my problem . Yes my df is like Lists in a list . I am able to write to a csv where the individual numbers are in column aligned beautifully. Only change I made is to write to csv :                                 

with open('file.csv','w') as f:
    writerfile=csv.writer(f,delimiter=' ')

    l=len(df.columnname)

    for i in range(0,l):
         row=("\n".join([sep.join(list(map(str, df.columnname[i]))) ]))
         print(row)
         writerfile.writerow([row])

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you may want to look into pandas or numpy, as they are optimized libraries created to deal with large quantities of data.

However, if your dataframe isn't that large and you don't want to resort to an external library, you can always use the `re.findall()` method to filter out your data, format it, and then just add the results to a dictionary.

```
import sys
import re

filename = sys.argv[1]
with open(filename, 'r') as input_file:
    input_data = input_file.read()

regex = r'\[(.+?)]'
filtered_data = re.findall(regex, input_data)

output_data = {}
for line in filtered_data:
    line_values = line.split(', ')
    for (j, value) in enumerate(line_values):
        if j not in output_data:
            output_data[j] = []

        output_data[j].append(value)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    for elements in output_data.values():
        output_file.write(', '.join(elements))
        output_file.write('\n')
```